# Asset validation failed. Invalid signature - flutter ios

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWnaz.png)

loading the application on TestFlight (using xCode or Transporter) ends with the errors "Asset validation failed. Invalid signature". this problem has appeared recently for 2 developers and on 2 different accounts with applications.

certificates were reissued, inserted automatically and manually - nothing helped. the xcode version is the latest stable.
thanks.